# ionic angularjs templateUrl rewrite issue

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

```
.state('app.item', {
        url: "/item/{title}",
        params: {
            color: null,
            icon: null
        },
        cache: false,
        views: {
            viewContent: {
                templateUrl: "templates/item.html",
                controller: 'ItemController'
            }
        }
    });
```

I want to rewrite the templateUrl like this

```
templateUrl:"templates/item/{title}.html",
```

I tried but doesn't work.

Comment: have you tried with double {{title}} and then i think you need to set the var title in the $rootScope.title="view1"

Answer (score 0):

I think you could solve it be adding a function and using the $stateParams service like this:

```
.state('app.item', {
        url: "/item/:title",
        params: {
            color: null,
            icon: null
        },
        cache: false,
        views: {
            viewContent: {
                templateUrl: function ($stateParams){
                    return 'templates/' + $stateParams.title + '.html';
                 },
                controller: 'ItemController'
            }
        }
    });
```